# How to combine InputKey and TaskKey into a new InputKey?

Tags: sbt

I have a SBT multi project which includes two sub projects. One is an ordinary Scala web server project and the other is just some web files. With my self written SBT plugin I can run Gulp on the web project. This Gulp task runs asynchronous. So with

```
sbt "web/webAppStart" "server/run"
```

I can start the Gulp development web server and my Scala backend server in parallel. Now I want to create a new task, that combines them both. So afterwards

```
sbt dev
```

for example should do the same. Here is what I tried so far:

```scala
// Build.sbt (only the relevant stuff)

object Build extends sbt.Build {
  lazy val runServer: InputKey[Unit] = run in server in Compile
  lazy val runWeb: TaskKey[Unit] = de.choffmeister.sbt.WebAppPlugin.webAppStart

  lazy val dev = InputKey[Unit]("dev", "Starts a development web server")

  // Scala backend project
  lazy val server = (project in file("project-server"))

  // Web frontend project
  lazy val web = (project in file("project-web"))

  // Root project
  lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .settings(dev <<= (runServer) map { (_) => {
      // do nothing
    })
    .aggregate(server, web)
```

This works so far. Now I don't have any idea, how to make `dev` also depend on the `runWeb` task. If I just add the `runWeb` task like

```scala
.settings(dev <<= (runWeb, runServer) map { (_, _) => {
  // do nothing
})
```

then I get the error

```
[error] /Users/choffmeister/Development/shop/project/Build.scala:59:value map is not a member of (sbt.TaskKey[Unit], sbt.InputKey[Unit])
[error]     .settings(dev <<= (runWeb, runServer) map { (_, _) =>
[error]                                           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

The optimal solution would pass the arguments given to `dev` to the `runServer` task. But I could also live with making `dev` a `TaskKey[Unit]` and then hard code to run `runServer` with no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Use `.value` macro to execute dependent tasks or just `alias` the task sequence.

### Using `.value` macro

Your case seems overly complicated to my eyes because of the pre-0.13 syntax (`<<=`) and the use of `project/Build.scala` (that often confuse not help people new to sbt).

You should just execute the two tasks in another as follows:

```scala
dev := {
  runWeb.value
  runServer.value
}
```

The complete example:

```scala
lazy val server = project

lazy val runServer = taskKey[Unit]("runServer")
runServer := {
  println("runServer")
  (run in server in Compile).value
}

lazy val runWeb = taskKey[Unit]("runWeb")
runWeb := {
  println("runWeb")
}

lazy val dev = taskKey[Unit]("dev")
dev := {
  println("dev")
}
dev <<= dev dependsOn (runServer, runWeb)
```

### Using `alias` command

sbt offers `alias` command that...

```
[sbt-learning-space]> help alias
alias

    Prints a list of defined aliases.

alias name

    Prints the alias defined for `name`.

alias name=value

    Sets the alias `name` to `value`, replacing any existing alias with that name.
    Whenever `name` is entered, the corresponding `value` is run.
    If any argument is provided to `name`, it is appended as argument to `value`.

alias name=

    Removes the alias for `name`.
```

Just define what tasks/command you want to execute in an alias as follows:

```
addCommandAlias("devAlias", ";runServer;runWeb")
```

Use `devAlias` as if it were a built-in task:

```
[sbt-learning-space]> devAlias
runServer
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 25, 2015 6:30:15 PM
runWeb
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 25, 2015 6:30:15 PM
```